# Bitcoin Miner Profit using 600 GH/s Monarch from Butterflylabs

Tags: mining-hardware

Butterflylabs has a new 600 GH/s [Bitcoin miner](http://www.butterflylabs.com/monarch/) for $2,196.

According to [here](http://dustcoin.com/), 600 GH/s at today's rate would mine approximately $170 a day. This means you make back the original cost of the miner in about two weeks and start making a profit from there on.

This seems too good to be true. Is there something I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The part you are missing is that it is a preorder and the current estimate is that if you ordered now, you would likely not receive your mining hardware until April 2014.

This site shows a good calculator and I have configured it to show the (lack of) profits you would make if you started mining with this miner starting in April:

http://mining.thegenesisblock.com/a/7141b8c779

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared things up. So this card is only profitable if the value of bitcoins increase with time?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Nice work Scott. Are there any ASICs out there that actually do justify investment?

Comment: Not that I believe and do trust me that I look.  The issue is that most ASICs that do justify an investment are preorders which unjustify the investment by the time you receive the ASICs in your hand.

Comment: This is quite interesting, thanks Scott. Are there historical graphs of the difficulty ?

Comment: Yes, right here: https://blockchain.info/charts/difficulty

Comment: or http://bitcoin.sipa.be